# Can I just upload High School certificate of my spouse for express entry?

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, express-entry

I have recently got express entry ITA for permanent resident. I'm currently at the document upload step. While uploading Education (diplomas/degrees) document for my spouse, I found they asked to upload post secondary diplomas/degrees. In help option i found this info- "You must provide proof that you completed your post-secondary education."

But the problem is, my spouse currently pursuing her post secondary/bachelor degree that's why she doesn't have any post-secondary diploma/degree certificate. She only has her High School diploma/degree certificate. Can anyone please suggest what to do in this case? would that be ok to just upload the high school certificate? Please note, i'm not claiming any points for my spouse. And also I'm falling under Canadian Experience class and PNP category.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically get a proof of education (called bona fide certificate in the country I used to live in) that your spouse is currently pursuing her post secondary/bachelor degree from the university/college that she is studying in and can upload that along with the high school certificate. That should be sufficient for her Education since you are not claiming any points based on her Education.